# when 2 output values are returned it should display the hardcorded one and if 1 output value is returned it should display the 1output itself

Tags: sql, oracle, set-operations

When I execute a query for input parameter `ABC` it returns two values `(Partner, Smith)`; whenever two values are returned of those two values Smith will be a compulsory value which will be returned.

But whenever the same query is executed with input parameter as `'xyz'` it returns only one value.

Now my requirement is whenever I execute a query if it returns two values of those two values only SMITH must be returned in output and if the same query returns one output value then it should display the `loutput` value itself.

The below query satisfies 1st part of my requirement but it doesn’t satisfy my 2nd part of the requirement. Instead of displaying the `1output` value it’s returning ‘Null’ value whenever the output value quantity is 1.

```
SELECT R.REGION_GID 
FROM GTM_TRANSACTION T, 
     GTM_TRANSACTION_INVOLVED_PARTY P,
     CONTACT C, 
     LOCATION L,
     REGION_DETAIL R 
WHERE T.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID=P.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID 
AND R.COUNTRY_CODE3_GID = L.COUNTRY_CODE3_GID 
AND R.REGION_GID LIKE 'SSN/BP.GTM_COMPL%' 
AND L.LOCATION_GID = C.LOCATION_GID 
AND P.INVOLVED_PARTY_CONTACT_GID=C.CONTACT_GID
AND P.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID='SHIP_FROM' 
AND T.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID=$SHIP_FORM 

INTERSECT

SELECT R.REGION_GID 
FROM GTM_TRANSACTION T,
     GTM_TRANSACTION_INVOLVED_PARTY P,
     CONTACT C,
     LOCATION L,
     REGION_DETAIL R 
    WHERE T.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID=P.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID
     AND R.COUNTRY_CODE3_GID = L.COUNTRY_CODE3_GID
      AND R.REGION_GID ='SSN/BP.GTM_COMPL_NO_CODING' 
    AND L.LOCATION_GID = C.LOCATION_GID  
    AND P.INVOLVED_PARTY_CONTACT_GID=C.CONTACT_GID 
    AND P.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID='SHIP_FROM'
      AND T.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID=$SHIP_FROM
```

Comment: So what is 'SMITH' in this process?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only difference between the two halves of your `INTERSECT` are in the filters for `P.REGION_GID`. The first half has:

```
R.REGION_GID LIKE 'SSN/BP.GTM_COMPL%'
```

while the second has

```
R.REGION_GID = 'SSN/BP.GTM_COMPL_NO_CODING'
```

Given how `INTERSECT` works, I think this means the first half is redundant. The only question then is whether the second half is returning one row or two rows. You want it to always return one row, with 'SMITH' taking precedence. The following logic may be what you want (as a bonus, I've tidied up your JOINs too):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    R.REGION_GID
FROM
    GTM_TRANSACTION T
    JOIN GTM_TRANSACTION_INVOLVED_PARTY P ON
        T.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID=P.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID
    JOIN CONTACT C ON
        P.INVOLVED_PARTY_CONTACT_GID=C.CONTACT_GID
    JOIN LOCATION L ON
        L.LOCATION_GID = C.LOCATION_GID 
    JOIN REGION_DETAIL R ON
        R.COUNTRY_CODE3_GID = L.COUNTRY_CODE3_GID 
WHERE
    R.REGION_GID ='SSN/BP.GTM_COMPL_NO_CODING'
    AND P.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID='SHIP_FROM'
    AND T.GTM_TRANSACTION_GID=$SHIP_FROM
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN R.REGION_GID = 'SMITH' then 1 else 2 end
```

That last line will want to be something like: `CASE WHEN R.REGION_GID = 'SMITH' then 1 else 2 end` but I you haven't told us much about your data, so I really don't know.

Comment: Not too sure what happened with my first version ... I must have lost some edits in my local version before I posted it and failed to notice. It's tidied up here.